# How can I create new column in data frame by aggregating rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large (~200k rows) dataframe that is structured like this:

```
df <-
 data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1), c('blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'), c('m','m','m','m','m'), c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),c(3,4,5,6,7), c(10,20,30,40,50))

colnames(df) <- c('id', 'color', 'size', 'year', 'week','revenue')
```

Let's say it is currently week 7, and I want to compare the trailing 4 week average of revenue to the current week's revenue. What I would like to do is create a new column for that average when all of the identifiers match.

```
df_new <-
 data.frame(1, 'blue', 'm', 2016,7,50, 25 )

colnames(df_new) <- c('id', 'color', 'size', 'year', 'week','revenue', 't4ave')
```

How can I accomplish this efficiently? Thank you for the help

Comment: Is your `df_new` supposed to *replace* the appropriate row or append it? Seems like you would need to use a grouping function (such as `by` or `dplyr::group_by`) with `zoo::rollapply`. What do you expect the value of this new column to be for the pre-existing rows?

Comment: Ideally it would append the existing row. So if df$week has values 3,4,5,6, or 7, the new column is created and t4ave is calculated for every unique permutation of the characteristics in week 7 (current week) and every value in with week = 3,4,5,6 would have t4ave = 0.  Any way to accomplish something similar would be helpful though

Comment: I understand logically what you want, and analytically find it difficult to deal with. By this I mean that it defeats the ideal nature of the data: you can now no longer assume that all rows have the same meaning: the row is a weekly sum unless there are two for the same week (et al), in which case one of them is weekly data, one is a 4-week summary, and to know that I need to know what the non-summary value of the summary column is ... and take the other ... do you see where I'm going with this? Perhaps if this were solely for output/reports then okay, but ...

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your concern. It is primarily for reporting purposes, specifically to look at how this week compares to the trailing four week average (which this week is not included in) to identify variables that spiked/dropped in the current week. Thanks for your help and thought into this thus far.

Answer (score 0):

good question. for loops are pretty inefficient, but since you do have to check the conditions of prior entries, this is the only solution I can think of (mind you, I'm also an intermediate at R):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    # condition for all entries to match up
    if ((i > 5) && (df$id[i] == df$id[i-1] == df$id[i-2] == df$id[i-3] == df$id[i-4])
    && (df$color[i] == df$color[i-1] == df$color[i-2] == df$color[i-3] == df$color[i-4])
    && (df$size[i] == df$size[i-1] == df$size[i-2] == df$size[i-3] == df$size[i-4])
    && (df$year[i] == df$year[i-1] == df$year[i-2] == df$year[i-3] == df$year[i-4])
    && (df$week[i] == df$week[i-1] == df$week[i-2] == df$week[i-3] == df$week[i-4]))

    # avg of last 4 entries' revenues
    avg <- mean(df$revenue[i-1] + df$revenue[i-2] + df$revenue[i-3] + df$revenue[i-4])

    # create new variable of difference between this entry and last 4's
    df$diff <- df$revenue[i] - avg
}
```

This code will probably take forever, but it should work. If this is a one time thing for when the code needs to run, then it should be okay. Otherwise, hopefully others will be able to advise.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the post that I tried a for loop - i ran it successfully for part of the df but when I tried to run the whole thing I got impatient after like 30 minutes and decided to post here. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: ah, I see...maybe run it overnight if you can't find a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `zoo`. The idea is to group the variable that are the same, such as `id`, `color`, `size`, and `year`. Aftet that, use `rollmean` to calculate the rolling mean of revenue. Use `na.pad = TRUE` and `align = "right"` to make sure the calculation covers the recent weeks. Finally, use `lag` to "shift" the calculation results to fit your needs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(id, color, size, year) %>%
  mutate(t4ave = rollmean(revenue, 4, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right")) %>%
  mutate(t4ave = lag(t4ave))
df2
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   id, color, size, year [1]
     id  color   size  year  week revenue t4ave
  <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   blue      m  2016     3      10    NA
2     1   blue      m  2016     4      20    NA
3     1   blue      m  2016     5      30    NA
4     1   blue      m  2016     6      40    NA
5     1   blue      m  2016     7      50    25
```